# delphi 2007 display unicode U+1F48B in UTF-8 string or any other way

Tags: delphi, sqlite, unicode, utf-8

I have a sqlite database (UTF-8 encoding). And inside the database i have such record (hex bytes):

```
D0 9E D0 BA 29 F0 9F 92 8B F0 9F 92 8B
```

Thus the bytes are not alligned, that is:

```
$D09E = O
$D0BA = к
$29 = )
$F09F928B = U+1F48b (KISS MARK)
$F09F928B = U+1F48b (KISS MARK)
```

This is how it looks like in the SQLite manager:

[image]

But whatever i do (UTF8Decode and some custom transformations) i cannot make it to be displayed in my Unicode enabled TNTStringGrid.

Yes, i can get the Ok)?? displayed but then goes either Ок)рџ’‹рџ’‹ or this is how it looks like real (UTF8Encoded): РћРє)рџ’‹рџ’‹

I know it's a hard question, but there must be a solution because the SQLite manager displays it absolutely correct.

So how to display those U+ characters along with normal text?

Please help! 3 days and nights fighting with this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Ok)??` means the UTF-8 data was correctly decoded to UTF-16, but then the UTF-16 data was converted to an Ansi codepage that does not support those Unicode characters.

`Ок)рџ’‹рџ’‹` means you have raw 8-bit UTF-8 octets being stored as-is, extended into 16-bit values, not being decoded from UTF-8 to UTF-16 at all.

Comment: Yes, that's obvious. The question is why in other software it is displayed correct? I have downloaded Delphi XE2 trial and well, it shows a bit better results (2 squares instead of rubbish) but still does not show the KISS MARKS. The SQLite manager software does not convert anything (it's javascript, so it's open to see)...

Comment: It is hard to answer that since you have not shown your actual code that is reading the data from the database.  You are likely using a method that is not UTF-8/Unicode enabled, so it is just returning the raw UTF-8 bytes as-is, which you are then interpretting as UTF-16 when it really is not.

Comment: Ok i read the blob to TMemoryStream, to avoid formatting, 
then i call UTF8DecodeString(StreamToString(blobData.Memory)); 
is what i do in Delphi XE2, in D2007 i tried RWideChar(blobData.Memory) and tried to convert it in different ways.

Comment: `UTF8DecodeString()` and `StreamToString()` are not ntive Delphi functions. If they are outputting the weird values you are seeing, then they are broken. In any case, to decode a `TMemoryStream` containing raw UTF-8 octets using native Delphi functionality, read the raw bytes as-is into a `UTF8String` variable, then in D2007 and earlier you can call `System.UTF8Decode()`, and in D2009+ you can simply assign the `UTF8String` to a `UnicodeString` directly.

Comment: Alternatively, on D2009+ only, you can use `TStringStream` instead of `TMemoryStream`, specifying `TEncoding.UTF8` in its constructor, then load the raw UTF-8 bytes into it and read its `DataString` property.  It will decode the bytes to Unicode.

Comment: UTF8DecodeString is equal to UTF8Decode. (It will call this function only) And the stream is TStringStream, sorry, i was not at the PC so couldn't check!
I have tried so many things so i could not remember exactly what is in the sources.
Thank You, Remy Lebeau, for still trying to help!

Comment: Okay! It worked with the Segoe UI Symbol Font!So what i did is:
blb := sltb.FieldAsBlob(i);
strst := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);
strst.LoadFromStream(blb);
dbview.Cells[Col, Row] := strst.DataString;
And the result was exactly as on the picture above! Thank You Remy!

Comment: `TStringStream` will work, but i still think using `UTF8String` is more direct and less overhead than `TStringStream`. But whatever works for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are dealing with UTF "Surrogate pairs":

Using UTF-16, the value ranges from $D800-DBFF and $DC00-DCFF are used to specify so-called surrogate pairs.
Using these surrogate pairs, we can map Unicode code points of $10000 and higher (in the range $10000 to $10FFFD).
This is done by subtracting $10000 from the value, leaving a value in the range 0 to $FFFFD, which can be represented in 20 bits.
These 20 bits are split in two pairs of 10 bits each, added to the $D800 resp. $DC00 pairs.
So for the Unicode code point $1D11E the UTF-16 surrogate pair is calculated as follows: first subtract $10000, which leaves $D11E,
which is 00001101000100011110 in 20 bits, split in $34 and $11E. $34 is added to $D800, and $11E is added to $DC00
resulting in $D834 for the most significant surrogate, and $DD1E for the least significant surrogate.

[Note that the Unicode code points $D800 to $DFFD will not be assigned a valid character by the Unicode standard (to avoid problems with UTF-16), so the individual surrogate characters are never mapped to actual characters themselves (but should always be used as a pair).]

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16

To properly display surrogate pair characters you need a font that contains them. E.g. the musical symbols in the range U+1D100 – U+1D1FF (119040–119295) are supported by the Windows fonts Code2001, Euterpe, Free Serif, Musica, Quivira, Symbola (http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/fontsbyrange.html#u1d100)
You need to download and install the Musica font (formerly called Musical Symbols) on your system in order for this example to work. Download location e.g. http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/
[Install under Win7: Right-click on the ttf file and choose 'install']
[Test page: http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/musical_symbols.html]

Here is my sample Delphi XE2 test code that uses the above (You have D2007, but this may get you on your way).

```
unit uSurrogatePairs;                                                                                                                    

interface                                                                                                                                

uses                                                                                                                                     
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,                                       
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;                                                                                    

type                                                                                                                                     
  TFrmSurrogatePairs = class(TForm)                                                                                                      
    MmoCharacter: TMemo;                                                                                                                 
    Mmo: TMemo;                                                                                                                          
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);                                                                                                 
  private                                                                                                                                
    procedure Log(S: String);                                                                                                            
  public                                                                                                                                 
    { Public declarations }                                                                                                              
  end;                                                                                                                                   

var                                                                                                                                      
  FrmSurrogatePairs: TFrmSurrogatePairs;                                                                                                 

implementation                                                                                                                           

{$R *.dfm}                                                                                                                               

type                                                                                                                                     
  TDanishString = type ansistring(1252);                                                                                                 

procedure TFrmSurrogatePairs.FormShow(Sender: TObject);                                                                                  
// Code adapted from http://compaspascal.blogspot.nl/2008/10/delphi-2009-strings-explained-by.html                                       
var                                                                                                                                      
  UTF16Str : string;                                                                                                                     
  UTF8Str  : utf8string;                                                                                                                 
  DanishStr: TDanishString;                                                                                                              
  L        : Integer;                                                                                                                    
begin                                                                                                                                    
{ TODO -oJan -cShouldHave : Test if Musica font is installed }                                                                           
  UTF16Str:=#$1D160;                                                                                                                     
  MmoCharacter.Text := UTF16Str;                                                                                                         
  L := length(UTF16Str);                                                                                                                 
  Assert (L=2);                                                                                                                          
  Log('Assigned: UTF16Str := #$1D160');                                                                                                  
  Log('  This is a musical note (000011101000101100000),');                                                                              
  log('  see http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U1D100.pdf');                                                                                 
  Log('Length(UTF16Str)=2');                                                                                                             
  Log('  This character occupies 2 positions in UTF-16');                                                                                
  Assert (UTF16Str[1]=#$D834);  // 110110 0000110100 First half of the symbol                                                            
  Assert (UTF16Str[2]=#$DD60);  // 110111 0101100000 Second half of the symbol                                                           
  Log('UTF16Str[1]=#$D834');                                                                                                             
  Log('UTF16Str[2]=#$DD60');                                                                                                             

  UTF8Str := utf8string(UTF16Str);                                                                                                       
  MmoCharacter.Lines.Add(String(UTF8Str));                                                                                               
  Log('');                                                                                                                               
  Log('Assigned: UTF8Str := UTF16Str');                                                                                                  
  Log('  This is the second line (char) in the left memo');                                                                              
  L := Length(UTF8Str);                                                                                                                  
  Assert (L=4);                                                                                                                          
  Log('Length(UTF8Str)=4');                                                                                                              
  Log('  This character occupies 4 positions in UTF-8, each 1 byte');                                                                    
  Assert (UTF8Str[1]=#$F0);   // 11110 000                                                                                               
  Assert (UTF8Str[2]=#$9D);   // 10 011101                                                                                               
  Assert (UTF8Str[3]=#$85);   // 10 000101                                                                                               
  Assert (UTF8Str[4]=#$A0);   // 10 100000                                                                                               

  DanishStr:=UTF16Str;                                                                                                                   
  Assert (DanishStr='??');    // Note how Windows incorrectly converts to two letters!                                                   
  Assert (length(DanishStr)=2);                                                                                                          
  DanishStr:=UTF8Str;                                                                                                                    
  Assert (DanishStr='??');    // Note how Windows incorrectly converts to two letters!                                                   
  Assert (length(DanishStr)=2);                                                                                                          
end;                                                                                                                                     

procedure TFrmSurrogatePairs.Log(S: String);                                                                                             
begin                                                                                                                                    
   Mmo.Lines.Add(S);                                                                                                                     
end;                                                                                                                                     

end.
```

and the DFM:

```
object FrmSurrogatePairs: TFrmSurrogatePairs
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Surrogate pairs'
  ClientHeight = 273
  ClientWidth = 600
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  OnShow = FormShow
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object MmoCharacter: TMemo
    AlignWithMargins = True
    Left = 3
    Top = 3
    Width = 134
    Height = 267
    Align = alLeft
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWindowText
    Font.Height = -107
    Font.Name = 'Musica'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentFont = False
    ReadOnly = True
    TabOrder = 0
  end
  object Mmo: TMemo
    AlignWithMargins = True
    Left = 143
    Top = 3
    Width = 454
    Height = 267
    Align = alClient
    Lines.Strings = (
      '')
    ReadOnly = True
    TabOrder = 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you Jan Doggen, for your outstanding post! Please, since i can't test your code, can you tell me, if i put the bytes above to a Memory Stream and then convert it to a string (UTFx or Unicode) - will it be displayed like in the example picture using Delphi > 2007? I just can't understand why the SQLManager is able to show combined fonts in same string (surrogate pairs) using a default font..

Comment: Sorry no, I don't know SQLite Manager. There must be a 'picture definition' of the kisses somewhere, which gets rendered on the screen. The obvious place for that info is the font definition. Your assumption that SQL Manager is using the default (system) font may be incorrect?